# How to include an MVC View into Master.master page

Tags: model-view-controller

There was a business requirement, where we have inherit/include "Master.Master" file into Mvc View[cshtml] .

I tried but doesn't find any solution.

Is there any way to achieve the above task.

Thanks in Advance

Abdul Aleem S

Comment: See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If including of "Master.Master" file into Mvc View[cshtml] was not possible, then is there any possibility of including "_layout.cshtml" page in "Master.master"